# regular expression does nothing in import.io

Tags: import.io

I'm trying to figure out how to use regular expressions on import.io.  I have an HTML column that successfully pulls data from a link on the web page.  I want to extract just part of the querystring on the link, so I go to the regexp field and enter a regular expression that tests successfully on regex101.com.  The problem is, the extracted data does not change at all.  In fact, I can type complete gibberish in the regexp field and it has absolutely no effect on the extracted data.  I'm a bit mystified.

If my regular expression is wrong, shouldn't the extracted data change to nothing?  Is there some trick to using the regexp field?  Do I have to enter something in the xpath field?  I clicked on View JSON button and copied the xpath for this column there and pasted that into the manual xpath box, but that didn't change anything either.

Is there a tutorial somewhere for how to use the regexp field?  And I'm not asking about how to use regular expressions, just the interface for it on import.io.

Comment: I may have figured this out.  You simply can't use regular expressions with an HTML column.  It has to be a Text column.

Answer (score 0):

Grant,

You are correct. At the moment it is not possible to apply regexp to HTML columns. There is a post in the idea forum capturing this as a feature request, you may want to upvote it, this way you'd also be notified if the idea gets built:

http://support.import.io/forums/199278-ideas-forum/suggestions/6328279-apply-regular-expressions-to-html